# send data inertia to laravel controller

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs

I make a drag and drop sortable list in inertia like this :

```
      <draggable 
        v-model="articles.data" 
        group="people" 
        @start="drag=true" 
        @end="drag=false" 
        item-key="id"
        :component-data="getComponentData()">
        <template #item="{element}">
          <div>{{element.title}}</div>
        </template>
      </draggable>
```

and i want to send the result order to my laravel controller, so i try this :

```
function handleChange() {
  Inertia.post('/TierList/update/', props.articles.data)
}
```

I was thinking i will get this in my request like this :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    dd("update", $request);
}
```

but i have nothing. this is what my dump send :

```
"update"
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request {#1122}
```

I know it is probably the wrong way, but with many search i'm still screwed up, if someone can send me some tips.

Comment: It's never a good idea to do `dd($request)`; the `$request` object is _huge_. If you want to see what you're `POST`-ing, do `dd($request->input())`, or `dd($request->all())` (useful if you're uploading files), or `return response()->json($request->input())`; sometimes `dd()` doesn't work great in AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just to replace $request to $request->all()

So i just chanded my code to this and that work:

```
public function update(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    dd("update", $request->all());
}
```